# How to call a fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-actionbaractivity

i wanna call a fragment from another activity which extends ActionBarActivity or Activity
i wanna make it like open an activity from another activity with intent

Comment: Your question is not really understandable, please elaborate your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments are not independent component like Activities. Fragments are attached to Activities. Hence, you have to make a View Pager or Frame Layout in your Activity and attach fragments to it.

Comment: immmmm ....
i have found a method ( startActivityFromFragment(fragment, intent, requestCode)) can it handle what i want